# Какие знаки препинания нужны в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

*И предлагать мне формулу женщине главное быть женой было бессмысленно.*

Какие знаки препинания нужны в этом предложении?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

И предлагать мне формулу "женщине главное — быть женой" было бессмысленно.

Тире ставится между подлежащим "главное" и связкой "быть".

Сравнить: для женщины главное — быть женой.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.

Comment: Спасибо, Sibylla!

Comment: Не думаю, что тире тут обязательно. Более того, оно тут вообще лишнее даже как авторский знак. Сейчас тире обязательно только в случае, если подлежащее и сказуемое выражено существительными в именительном падеже и в некоторых семантически и стилистически окрашенных  случаях. ***Перед "быть"  вообще говоря не требутся. Кстати "быть"  и не связка в данном случае, а смысловой глагол.*** Подробности тут: http://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827474.html

Comment: Из Нацкорпуса: Главное― понять, что нет двух состояний "знания языка". Главное ― не сооружать искусственные преграды. И т.д. Главное ― это прилагательное, перешедшее в СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНОЕ, такие слова могут обозначать отвлеченные понятия (будущее, прекрасное, главное).  И тогда правило постановки тире распространяется и на это слово. И по поводу связки: если считать "быть" смысловым глаголом, то получится "для женщины главное ―быть/существовать".

Comment: Тире: Alt+0151, прошу прощения, Sibylla.

Comment: @Morkovkin *Кстати "быть" и не связка в данном случае, а смысловой глагол.* - вот тут сомневаюсь. Хотя что-то в этом есть, здесь же быть в значении "являться". Но это надо всю грамматику переворачивать. В существующем подходе до смыслового не дотягивает. Пусть уж связкой останется, как учили "от табуретки". Или сейчас стали по-новому учить? Или придется вводить новое понятие "вспомогательно-смысловой глагол (не связка)".

Comment: @Morkovkin Насчет тире. Тоже в чем-то согласен, тире вообще говоря не требуется, но, думаю, что вполне возможно для общей выразительности, это ведь как лозунг получается. А лозунг требует особых средств,  Тот самый "стилистически окрашенный"  случай.

Answer (score 1):

Кавычки: *И предлагать мне формулу "женщине главное быть женой" было бессмысленно.*
Ничего другого тут в голову прийти не может.

Answer (score 0):

И предлагать мне формулу "женщине главное - быть женщиной" было бессмысленно. Думаю, что слово "женщине" может начинаться и с большой буквы.

Comment: «главное - быть» ====== И чёрточка, думаете, тоже может быть?